# MySQL table creation fails with error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE BestSinger(
     RapperID INT,
     FirstName VARCHAR(22),
     NicName VATCHAR (16),
    LastName VARCHAR(28),
     PRIMARY KEY (singer));


CREATE TABLE WorstSinges(
     Phone INT,
     ClassName VARCHAR(30),
     PRIMARY KEY (Singer));


 CREATE TABLE PriceForWinner (
     FirstPlace INT,
     SecondPlace INT,
     ThirdPlace DATE,
 );
```

Add a record NETURAL to  worstSinger
Add Marvin T. Wade, Jimie Z, Johnson, and  P Jacque to the NEUTRAL record
Add Foday U. James, Alfred D. Sync to Best Singer
Use the SELECT STATEMENT to display data you added to best singer table

Comment: You have specified primary key columns for the tables that are not actually in those tables.

Answer (score 2):

a) The following script

```
CREATE TABLE BestSinger(
     RapperID INT,
     FirstName VARCHAR(22),
     NicName VATCHAR (16),
    LastName VARCHAR(28),
     PRIMARY KEY (singer));
```

Should corrected as

```
CREATE TABLE BestSinger(
     RapperID INT,
     FirstName VARCHAR(22),
     NicName VARCHAR (16),
    LastName VARCHAR(28),
     PRIMARY KEY (singer));
```

It is `VARCHAR` and not VATCHAR. It's a typo.

b) Column name '`singer`' is use to define constraint but it does not exist in your tables columns definition.

Fixing issues described under (a) and (b), you can define script as below (assuming your constraint field is of type `INT`)

```
CREATE TABLE BestSinger(Singer INT, RapperID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(22), NicName VARCHAR (16), LastName VARCHAR(28), PRIMARY KEY (singer));
CREATE TABLE WorstSinges(Singer INT,Phone INT, ClassName VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (Singer));
CREATE TABLE PriceForWinner ( FirstPlace INT, SecondPlace INT, ThirdPlace DATE, );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change data type of column NicName to VARCHAR(16) from VATCHAR(16)